# Is there a way to filter the activity list?

Tags: trello

When you click on a card to see its expanded information, you see an **Activity** section which displays a list of both **comments** and the automatically-generated *"[name] moved this card from [list] to [list]"*-type of items.

Is there a way to filter this list so that it only displays **comments**? Or, better put, is there a filter anywhere?

Or is the fact that I need this a sign that I might be Doing It Wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trello doesn't currently allow you to filter activity lists.

Answer (score 0):

Trello does not allow this, but you can hide the activity list using a greasemonkey script.

[Script code at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eSxriXg6)