# Hiding On Card Status Activity But Not Comments in Trello

Tags: trello

Currently each card I have has the activity relating to the card on it. As I have the stream on the left I don't need this. Is there any way to disable this without also hiding comments?

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19347/is-there-a-way-to-filter-the-activity-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a way to do this, no.

Comment: Is there a possibility that this is going to happen in the future? Some cards have long conversations and don't really need a complete activity feed underneath it. A switch between activity and comments would be a nice addon.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in trello but you can hide activity using a Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey script from here - http://pastebin.com/eSxriXg6

Comment: I wrote that userscript originally, and since then Trello has changed — you can find the update here: http://beingmrkenny.co.uk/trello-user-scripts/